# How to put 2 customViews inside a dynamic RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-relativelayout, custom-view

I got the following `customViews`:

```
val paintTextTypology = Paint()
val paintTextDate = Paint()
```

This 2 texts are the following `customViews`:
[image]

And the result I want to achieve is this: [image]

So I want to align the text to right, but since the texts are separated, I think I have to create a dynamic `RelativeLayout` to align them to the right of the parent.
(I can't afford to have `margin-right` because the text can change.) 
How can I do it?

Comment: Hi Pedro, I think you need to provide a little bit of a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve. First advice is: don't use a relative layout. Use ConstraintLayout right out of the box.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I can use Constraint Layout, but how I can create one dynamically and then put the 2 customviews inside of it? Only this way I can relate them... Thank you @MartinMarconcini

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment (not 100% clear to me yet because I don't know what your *custom views* are), I would use a ConstraintLayout that would look like this:

The red rectangle is your picture.
And then I added two textViews which are aligning to the image. You can play with it and see what else you need. (this is a simplification).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is textView One"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is textView Two -> longer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@color/emphasis_red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This would look like this:

[image: Emulator]

Comment: It can't be in XML...it should be all in kotlin because all should be in onDraw(canvas: Canvas) function

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to draw text using the canvas and a Paint object, I suggest you create a custom view inflated from XML with TextViews instead. One of the reasons why you'd want to do this, is **because it would solve this problem for you**; when you _paint_ to a Canvas, there is no margin, kerning, RTL support, etc. You simply draw a path on a canvas.